# Cannot call functions from another deployed contract that inherits yet another contract

Tags: solidity, remix, inheritance

I am just trying this using Remix editor. I am able to call functions from another deployed contract(plain as simple) but when that another deployed contract inherits yet another contract, Now the calling functions from the original contract to the deployed contract doesn't work. I just get a `transaction revert`

Working Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
contract Existing {
    Deployed public dc;
    constructor(address _deployedContractAddress) public {
        dc = Deployed(_deployedContractAddress);
    }

    function setA(uint _a) public returns (uint) {
        return dc.setA(_a);
    }
    function getA() public view returns (uint) {
        return dc.a();
    }
}

contract Deployed {
    uint public a = 1;

    function setA(uint _a) public returns (uint) {
        a = _a;
        return a;
    }

}
```

**Not Working Code:**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
contract Existing {
    Deployed public dc;
    constructor(address _deployedContractAddress) public {
        dc = Deployed(_deployedContractAddress);
    }

    function setA(uint _a) public returns (uint) {
        return dc.setA(_a);
    }
    function getA() public view returns (uint) {
        return dc.a();
    }
}


contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

}

contract Deployed is Ownable {
    uint public a = 1;

    function setA(uint _a) public onlyOwner returns (uint) {
        a = _a;
        return a;
    }

}
```

So here, the `contract Deployed` is inheriting from `contract Ownable` and I just get a `transaction revert` on calling `setA`

**Note: `contract Deployed` is seperately deployed in a separate file and also included in `contract Existing` file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the inheritance but in the logic of which address owns which contract. In the second (non-working) example if you remove the `onlyOwner` modifier from the function it works just fine.

In the non-working example this is what happens:

1) You deploy contract `Deployed` from your wallet, let's say its address is `0x123`. That wallet becomes the owner of `Deployed` (as per the contract `Ownable`).

2) You deploy contract `Existing` from the same wallet. No ownership is present here.

3) Contract `Existing` uses the existing instance of `Deployed` for making a call to it. Here `msg.sender` is `0x123`.

4) When the call from `Existing` to `Deployed` reaches `Deployed` the `msg.sender` is the originating contract's address - so the address of `Existing`. That contract is not the owner of `Deployed` as the owner is `0x123`. Therefore, as the function requires that only the owner can call it, the call fails and the whole transaction is reverted.

Comment: Thanks :)  this explains a lot. Could you please suggest me a solution here?


Note: I still want to be able to access the deployed version of `contract Deployed`

Comment: Umh, sorry, I have no idea what you really want to accomplish so I can't really suggest anything. But now you know how it works so you should be able to write something that suits your needs better. Or post a new question if you have further problems